# Node.JS Invalid URI Error: GET Request using Query parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to do query to find a account using rest services of the target application name hexion.
When I am running it is giving Invalid uri error.
The url that I tested in postman is like below
https://ekaa-dev1.fa.us6.oraclecloud.com/crmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/accounts?q=OrganizationName = Hexion

and in postman I am getting response too.
But I feel somewhere in my code I am doing some syntax error but not able to find that

```
//nodejs v4.2.6

console.log("Hello, World!");
var Request = require("request");
var serviceUserName="msonawane@gmail.com";
var password="Welcome01";
var personalDataURL="https://ekaa-dev1.fa.us6.oraclecloud.com/crmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/accounts";
var option1 = {
        uri:  personalDataURL,
        qs: {
            q:{OrganizationName:"Hexion"}
             },
        headers: {
            "Authorization" : auth,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            "Accept":'application/json'
        }

    };

var auth = `Basic ` + new Buffer(serviceUserName+`:`+password).toString(`base64`);

Request.get(option1, { json: true },
     (error, response, body) => {
         console.log(response);
             //console.log(response.url);
         if (error) { return console.log(body,error); }
  console.log(body.url);
  console.log(body.explanation);
     });
```

I expect it to return response after successful get
Please let me know error, I have changed the auth credentials so once you find anything to be corrected let me for the above code, I will try with right credentials and update you

Comment: What is the error content?

Comment: @Flo Error: Invalid URI "/"]

Comment: @Flo: do you find anything suspicious on the code that you want me  try correcting it out

Comment: Anyone can help here

Answer (score 1):

request.get method expects first parameter as url, but you are passing options1 obj, it couldn't find url hence it is giving error "Invalid uri /".
You can append query parameter to url OR use [querystring npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring)

```
var personalDataURL= "https://ekaa-dev1.fa.us6.oraclecloud.com/crmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/accounts?q=OrganizationName=Hexion"
    request({
        headers: {
                "Authorization" : auth,
                "Content-Type": 'application/json',
                "Accept":'application/json'
            },
        uri: personalDataURL,
        method: 'GET'
      }, function (err, res, body) {
        //it works!
      });
```

For more details, refer [request](https://github.com/request/request)

Comment: it is throwing error as below Hello, World!

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jdoodle.js:4:15)

Comment: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
Command exited with non-zero status 1

Comment: You need to install request npm by executing "npm i request --save" command